# How to write a socket server in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, swift3

I want to communicate two iOS devices in local area network via socket. 
Right now, I am able to communicate with web socket by writing a client side code in iOS, but i want to know there is any way to communicate two iOS devises via socket, so one iOS device work as server and other iOS device work as a client.

For Client side i am using below code:

```
// MARK:- communication initilaize Methode.
   func initNetworkCommunication() {

        //Initilize network communication.

        host = "192.168.2.15" //Server IP
        port = 8788 //Port for communication

        Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: host!, port: port!, inputStream: &inputstream, outputStream: &outputstream)

        if ((inputstream != nil) && (outputstream != nil)) {
            // connection  not failed.
            print("Connection to \(host!):\(port!)")

            inputstream?.delegate = self
            outputstream?.delegate = self


            inputstream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
            outputstream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

            inputstream?.open()
            outputstream?.open()

        }
    }
```

And for handling a connection, implement a delegate of `StreamDelegate` as:

```
 // MARK:- StreamDelegate Methods.
 func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {

       switch eventCode {

            case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
                print("Connected")

                //Make connection connect.
                outputstream_Status = true

                break

            case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
                break

            case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
                break

            case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
                print("Connection closed by the server.")

                //Make connection disconnect.
                outputstream_Status = false

                //De-Initialize the Stream.
                closeNetworkCommunication()

                break

            case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:

                print("Can not connect to the host!")

                //Make connection disconnect.
                outputstream_Status = false

                break

            default:
                break
            }
      }
 }
```